# Effect of sleep deprivation on pupils and pupillary responses

Tags: sleep

What is the effect, if any, of sleep deprivation on pupils? Specifically:

- Are pupils more dilated/constricted?
- Is the pupillary response to light any different?
- Anything else?

Comment: Are you referring to pupil measurements in passive subjects, or when engaged in cognitively demanding tasks? In other words, are you talking about pupil size as such, or to pupil responses during task performance?

Comment: Both, if possible. I was talking about effect on pupil size, and pupillary response to light, but if there is any other effect of sleep deprivation on pupils, such as a change in pupil responses during task performance, I would be grateful if I could know about that, too.

Comment: It's always best to ask specific questions. Broad inquiries like this question as it stands tend to result in open ended discussions.

Comment: Okay then, I am referring to pupil measurements in passive subjects.